# ABAP: how to get transaction's parameter name to use in SET PARAMETER ID?

Tags: abap

SET PARAMETER ID 'MAT' FIELD '470000-001' .  " 'MAT' is the parameter id of material input in MM03

CALL TRANSACTION 'MM03' AND SKIP FIRST SCREEN .

Specifically I need parameter ID for ME23 transaction, but it would be good to know the common way to get such information.

Comment: If you look at the Dynpro, you see all the fields which are assigned parameter IDs (the IDs may come from data elements). Sometimes, the application can itself do a `GET PARAMETER ID` that you can "trace" by using a "statement breakpoint".

Answer (score 1):

Call the transaction, place the cursor on the field and press F1. Now click on the "Technical Information" button in the toolbar of the help popup. Another popup will appear showing the parameter ID in section "Field data" (if any).

In some rare cases the initial values for the screen fields are populated by the ABAP coding of the transaction. In this case you need to check the coding in the PBO modules of the first screen.

Not every field can be populated using a parameter ID. You can use CALL TRANSACTION ... USING ... MODE ... OPTIONS FROM ... to populate the fields in one or more screens and continue in dialog mode. See ABAP documentation for further details.